# Can I connect client to multiple parse servers?

Tags: javascript, parse-server

I am trying to connect different react components in the same app to multiple parse servers but I can only connect to one parse server.

App.js is the parent component and App2.js is the child component.

I have started 2 parse servers, each running on different ports.

Parse server A runs on port 1330, 1331 (livequery) while the other server B runs on port 1337, 1338 (livequery). 
I tried to connect App.js to A and App2.js to B but App2.js still connects to A.

Is it possible to connect App2.js to both server A and B?

```
in App.js:

import { Parse as UserParse } from "parse";
UserParse.initialize("APP_ID");
UserParse.serverURL = "http://localhost:1330/parse";
UserParse.liveQueryServerURL = "ws://localhost:1331/";

in App2.js:

import {Parse as DataParse } from "parse";
DataParse.initialize("APPLICATION_ID")
DataParse.serverURL = "http://localhost:1337/parse"
DataParse.liveQueryServerURL = "ws://localhost:1338/"
```

Errors encountered:

RESTController.js:205 POST http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/400 (Bad Request)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid session token at RESTController.js:319

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do that using the JS SDK. The JS SDK does not support multiple apps since some of its methods (for instance, the `Parse.initialize()`) are static. So any change in the initialization will affect the SDK globally.

If you need to connect to different apps from the client side, you will have to use the [REST API](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/) or the [GraphQL API](http://docs.parseplatform.org/graphql/guide/) directly, without using the JS SDK (or using the SDK for one app and one of the APIs for the other app).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this `initializeMulti`-function which seems to do the job:

```
  var Parse = require('parse/node')

  Parse.initializeMulti = (appId, javascriptKey, masterKey) => {
      Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function(key) { delete require.cache[key] })
      var _Parse = require('parse/node')
      _Parse.initialize( appId, javascriptKey, masterKey )
      return _Parse
  }

  Parse.foo = Parse.initializeMulti('foo','foo','foo')
  Parse.foo.serverURL = 'http://localhost/foo'

  Parse.bar = Parse.initializeMulti('bar','bar','bar')
  Parse.bar.serverURL = 'http://localhost/bar'

  console.dir( Parse.foo.CoreManager.get('APPLICATION_ID') )   // foo
  console.dir( Parse.bar.CoreManager.get('APPLICATION_ID') )   // bar
```